# Creating file with & in batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a VBS file that includes `&` in it that changes volume using batch (Below)

```
(
echo Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
echo WshShell.SendKeys(chr(&hAF))
)> KXV.vbs
```

^ which should create KXV.vbs including that text

I've browsed for some time, but if I missed something I'm sorry. I tried using `^&` but that makes it print instead. The volume change is fine but `&` keeps making it error:

> (WshShell.SendKeys(chr(
>
> 'hAF))' is not recognized as an internal or external command,)
> operable program or batch file.

Sorry if my spelling, grammar, or anything else is off.

Comment: You need to also escape the closing parentheses otherwise you are closing the command block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the closing parentheses too in order to create your vbs file correctly :

```
(
    echo Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
    echo WshShell.SendKeys(chr(^&hAF^)^)
)>KXV.vbs
```